# Error when installing qca-ossl plugin

Tags: encryption, compile, qt, openssl

I have been trying to compile and install the qca-ossl plugin for QCA and Qt.
I installed Qt, QCA and openssl without any problems. But now I have to compile qca-ossl.

While compiling I got some errors. The error is given below, please check it and please help me solve this issue!

```
C:\qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3>mingw32-make
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3'
C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DOSSL_097 -DQT_DL
L -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\QtCo
re" -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\include" -I"..\local\include" -I"..\qca-2.0.3\include\Qt
Crypto" -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\mksp
ecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 qca-ossl.cpp -o debug\qca-ossl.moc
g++ -c -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -
DOSSL_097 -DQT_DLL -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -I"..\Qt\2010.0
5\qt\include\QtCore" -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\include" -I"..\local\include" -I"..\qca
-2.0.3\include\QtCrypto" -I"..\Qt\2010.05\qt\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"..\Q
t\2010.05\qt\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\qca-ossl.o qca-ossl.cpp
qca-ossl.cpp: In function 'X509_EXTENSION* opensslQCAPlugin::new_subject_key_id(
X509*)':
qca-ossl.cpp:339: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

windres -i qca-ossld_resource.rc -o debug\qca-ossld_resource_res.o --include-dir
=. -DUNICODE -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DOSSL_097 -DQT_DLL -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_CORE_LI
B -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-rel
oc -mthreads -Wl -shared -Wl,--out-implib,lib\libqca-ossld2.a -o lib\qca-ossld2.
dll debug/qca-ossl.o  -L"c:\Qt\2010.05\qt\lib" debug\qca-ossld_resource_res.o -L
C:/local/lib -llibeay32 -lssleay32 -lgdi32 -lwsock32 -LC:/qca-2.0.3/lib -lqcad -
lQtCored4
c:/qt/2010.05/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
 cannot find -lqcad
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [lib\qca-ossld2.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/qca-ossl-2.0.0-beta3'
mingw32-make: *** [debug-all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I read somewhere that it cant create debug files by itslef. so i tried using configwin.bat r simply. and it worked.